# DocuSign work space functionality to acknowledge more than one envelopes at a time

Tags: docusignapi

Currently in our application user has to accept one envelope at a time to acknowledge. can we merge or make Docu Sign work space functionality to acknowledge more than one envelopes at a time.
So that user can select multiple envelopes and on acknowledging once all envelopes should get acknowledged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way you can acknowledge more than one envelope at one time (or in single click). But you can have a concept of Workspace in DocuSign, which means you will be taken to a place/screen where you will see all the envelopes which you need to take action on. And from that screen, acknowledge all the envelope and no need to search each and every emails for this. Check [DocuSign Workspaces](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Workspaces/) for more details

Comment: Thanks for the reply. as of now we are using RequestRecipientToken which gives the url for specific envelope and this url will be displayed in IFrame. where user can accept the envelope inside docu sign. is there any way we can display work space to user. .the concern here is user will not have a docu sign account before sending these envelopes . so  by accessing the URL will the user be able to acknowledge the envelopes or he need to login to docu sign ?

Comment: Workspaces is not for embedded signers, it can only be used with remote signers. And remote signers need not to have DocuSign account, as email will go to their email inbox and workspace will be accessed with from their email only.